# Magento: Unable to override Sales Rule

Tags: php, magento, overriding, url-rewriting

I am unable to override Sales Rule Model. I want to override class **Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule**.

Here is my code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyNamespace_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <rule>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Rule</rule>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

But this doesn’t work.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you post the XML snippet in the context of your full configuration file?  Best guess is it's in the wrong location.

Comment: @AlanStorm: I have updated the XML snippet. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You seem to be missing your outer <config/> node.

Comment: @AlanStorm: Sorry. It was not full XML snippet before. Now, I have updated with the full XML snippet. Can you please check it again?

Comment: The config looks correct.  What makes you think you haven't created the rewrite successfully?

Comment: I agree with the big AS, this config is correct.  Have you checked that your module is being instantiated? Does it show in the list under System > Configuration > Advanced?

Comment: Also, there's the free module list module, which can tell you which modules are enabled/disabled, as well as troubleshot common issues http://alanstorm.com/magento_list_module (ye olde self link)

Comment: The module is instantiated (System -> Configuration -> Advanced). I tried to override a block through the module and it worked fine. However, I am unable to override salesrule model class :(

Comment: Check for other modules that may also be overriding the same model. Especially those in 'local' since they take precedence.

Comment: I would check what class is returned when you call get_class(Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')); - If its not the standard magento class, you will know which module already overrides this model.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for helping in debugging my problem.

The problem is solved now.

I had written the override code in another local module XML file as well. However, I had commented that code and my cache is disabled. But, I don't know how it was causing problem. So, when I removed that commented code (from another module) then my problem was solved and I was able to override salesrule model.

I would like to write some tips for others if they face such problem. These tips are based on the comments in this question.

- Recheck if your XML snippet is in the right location.
- Check if the module is being instantiated (System -> Configuration -> Advanced).
- Check for other modules that may also be overriding the same model. Especially those in 'local' since they take precedence.
- Check what class is returned when you call your desired class:

  `echo get_class(Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule'));`

Thank you all for your comments.